# Entity Framework adds new record for navigation property

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I have two entities, defined as following

```
public class Corporation
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public List<Location> Locations{get;set;} // All locations under this corp
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public Corporation Corporation{get;set;} // Corporation is required in configuraion
}
```

When I try to add a Corporation and then a location, I get two Corporation defined. One by my function that adds Corporation(which is fine), and one by the function that adds location(which is the issue).

Location adding function is like this:

```
public void AddLocation(int locationId)
{
     using (Context context = new Context())
     {
          Location location = new Location();
          location.Corporation = GetCorporationFromDb(corpId);

          context.Locations.Add(location); // This one adds another same Corporation to DB
          context.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

How can I avoid this? I have to add Corporation before Location because in the implementation Location calculates an electronic code using Corporation's database Id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens if you fetch the corporation from a different data context than the one you use to add the location. Try:

```
Context context = new Context();
Location location = new Location();
Corporation corporation = context.Corporations
    .Where(x => x.Id == corpId)
    .First();
location.Corporation = corporation;

context.Locations.Add(location);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This way, you use the same context for retrieving the `Corporation` and adding the `Location`.

Comment: its also possible to attach an object which was loaded from another context into the new context...

Comment: This is possibly the cause of the issue. I will try what you suggested when I get to work.

Comment: I want to add location in a seperate method. Should I pass the context as a parameter to that function and add the location? Does passing the context to another method cause problem?

Comment: No it shouldn't. When you start doing stuff this, also look at manual method injection, which is a part of dependency injection. Ideally, you want a method which initiates the `DbContext`, and passes it to both the `AddLocation` and `AddCorporation` methods.

Comment: Using same context didn't solve. Can it be some kind of relation configuration issue?

Comment: It could be, because the way I described it is the default EF behavior. Did you define the mappings manually? When I define the mappings manually, I always define them on both sides (so a `Corporation.HasMany()` and a `Location.HasRequired()`), and I have never had the problems that you are describing. You could also look at attaching the entities to the context like @RicoSuter advised, as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6250929/747128), but I have no experience with that method so I can't advise you there.