# WPF Entity Framework, Include doubles data

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Im currently working on a project in WPF with a Entity Framework in tha back.
I have a table called Category which contains Id, CatNumber, CatName.
I also have a Product table where a product have a one-to-one relationship to Category.
Currently im trying to create some sort of unit of work service that has using around it, so dont have to open context during the lifespan of tha application. 
On one of my questions to the DBContext i want a list of all articles on one Order. I try to use:

```
from model in
mainDBContext.Include(o=>o.OrderList.Select(p=>p.Articles.Select(c=>c.Category))) 
where model.CustomerID == 5 select model
```

The problem i am having is that when saving changes to the articles it updates my Category table with a new row with duplicate data from the row of my articles. 
The article row now have a categoryID connection to the new added row instead of the first one.

Is there a problem with the Includes or is it a problem with the relations or...?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249837/entity-framework-creates-foreign-key-objects-instead-of-using-those-that-are-alr

Comment: Thanks, i will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you trying to update your entity, the entity is belongs to another context which you get it from that, All thing you should do is to attach your entity to your current context, some code like that:

```
context.Articles.Attach(*YourEntityInstance*);
```

Comment: Thanks, but if i have a Complex object as an Order, which contains a list of articles that contains the category. Do i need to loop over all the articles and acces the Category object and do Attach on them all?

Comment: @Mrq Yes, you should implement an easy method and attach all childs which are not in context in any deep level you need